# Visa application payment declined due to error

Tags: visas, uk, payment

I applied for a UK business visa. I got a mail from the UK embassy that my application falls under the short-term student visa. So they withdrew my application and suggested me to submit another application for a short-term student visa within two days.

Yesterday I submitted the application. When I was paying the fee I got a message the payment was successful. Later, I got a mail stating that the visa fee payment was declined. The reason may be:

1. Some of the card/personal details entered do not match the information held by the card issuer.
2. I do not have enough cleared funds on the card to cover the amount of the purchase

They asked me to do the payment once again. But once I open my account it shows the application is complete and the payment is already done. There is no link for payment and the amount is also not credited to my account. So I am confused about what should be done.

Answer (score 13):

> But once I open my account it shows the application is complete and the payment is already done. There is no link for payment and the amount is also not credited to my account.

Ignore the second email saying your payment was rejected, attend your appointment and they will know exactly what's the status. If for some reason the payment did not go through they will ask you to pay there so keep a plan ready to pay right there and then you can dispute your previous payment with your bank.

Had your payment not gone through there was a strong chance you would not be able to continue to the next stage. I am sure that the payment denial email was a technical glitch. If they ask you then instead of just paying right away first do mention that the funds have been deducted from your account and your UKVI account says that the payment has been received.

Don't just go in and say oh here take the payment again.